# How to sort products inside a particular category by price, news & popularity or by Customer review in Magento in Android using kSOAP2

Tags: android, magento, soap, android-ksoap2

I am making an Android application which communicates with Magento SOAP v2 API's for getting products & buying products. I want to know that how can I sort products inside a particular category by price, news & popularity or by customer review in Magento in Android using kSOAP2 library.

I searched on internet but could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Magento SOAP API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html) documentation, that is not possible.

But you can retrieve products from this API then apply the chosen order from Java through [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

Comment: What do you mean by this API?

Comment: You can retrieve products list from API and should get something like List<Product>. You can then sort this List thanks to Collections.sort.
(Sample Comparator implementation : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/sorting.html)

Comment: But for that I will have to load all products at once which is not possible.